# FontHandler exception during report generation with birt engine

Tags: java, report, birt

i am getting below excpetion during birt report generation. Given below the code with stack trace.

do i need to add any other font related files in my application? 
Does anybody have an idea on this.

It is working fine when i have render option as 'HTML'. Throwing below exception only when i have render option as 'pdf'.

> BirtEngineDesktop.java: import java.io.File; import
>   java.io.FileInputStream; import java.util.HashMap; import
>   java.util.logging.Level; import
>   org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.BirtException; import
>   org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform; import
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.*;
>
> public class BirtEngineDesktop {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>     String reportName = "new_report_2.rptdesign";
>     IReportEngine engine = null;
>     IReportRunnable design = null;
>     IRunAndRenderTask task = null;
>     PDFRenderOption renderContext = null;
>     HashMap contextMap = null;
>     PDFRenderOption options = null;
>     final EngineConfig conf = new EngineConfig();
>     conf.setEngineHome("ReportEngine");
>     System.out.println("BIRT_HOME: " + conf.getBIRTHome());
>     conf.setLogConfig(null, Level.FINE);
>
>     try {
>         Platform.startup(conf);
>     } catch (BirtException e1) {
>         e1.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>     IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
>             .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
>     engine = factory.createReportEngine(conf);
>
>     try {
>         design = engine.openReportDesign(reportName); 
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         System.err.println("An error occured during the opening of the report file!");
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         System.exit(-1);
>     }
>     task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
>     renderContext = new PDFRenderOption();
>     contextMap = new HashMap();
>     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test\\sample.xml"));
>     contextMap.put("org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.inputStream",fis);     
>     contextMap.put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_PDF_RENDER_CONTEXT,
>             renderContext);
>     task.setAppContext(contextMap);
>
>
>     options = new PDFRenderOption();
>     options.setOutputFileName("D://"+reportName + ".pdf");         options.setOutputFormat("pdf");
>     task.setRenderOption(options);
>     try {
>         task.run();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         System.exit(-1);
>     }
>    engine.destroy();
>     System.exit(0);
> } }
> ```

And my stack trace is:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask handleFatalExceptions

SEVERE: An error happened while running the report. Cause:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontHandler.getMappedFont(FontHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontHandler.selectFont(FontHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontSplitter.buildChunk(FontSplitter.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontSplitter.getNext(FontSplitter.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.text.ChunkGenerator.getNext(ChunkGenerator.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextCompositor.getNextTextArea(TextCompositor.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextCompositor.getNextArea(TextCompositor.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextAreaLayout.layoutChildren(TextAreaLayout.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextAreaLayout.layout(TextAreaLayout.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.InlineTextArea.layout(InlineTextArea.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startContent(LayoutEngine.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startText(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startLabel(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startForeign(LayoutEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitChildren(LayoutEngine.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.RegionLayoutEngine.layout(RegionLayoutEngine.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.PageArea.layoutFooter(PageArea.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.PageArea.initialize(PageArea.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.RootArea.createNewPage(RootArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.RootArea.initialize(RootArea.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.setContainer(LayoutEngine.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine._startContainer(LayoutEngine.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startContainer(LayoutEngine.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startPage(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.CompositeContentEmitter.startPage(CompositeContentEmitter.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.PageNode.start(PageNode.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.ContainerBufferNode.start(ContainerBufferNode.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.ContainerBufferNode.start(ContainerBufferNode.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.ContainerBufferNode.start(ContainerBufferNode.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.ContainerBufferNode.start(ContainerBufferNode.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.HTMLPageBuffer.startContent(HTMLPageBuffer.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.TableBreakBuffer.startContent(TableBreakBuffer.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLLeafItemLM.start(HTMLLeafItemLM.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableBandLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableBandLM.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at BirtEngineDesktop.main(BirtEngineDesktop.java:69)
An error occured while running the report!
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2329)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at BirtEngineDesktop.main(BirtEngineDesktop.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontHandler.getMappedFont(FontHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontHandler.selectFont(FontHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontSplitter.buildChunk(FontSplitter.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontSplitter.getNext(FontSplitter.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.text.ChunkGenerator.getNext(ChunkGenerator.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextCompositor.getNextTextArea(TextCompositor.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextCompositor.getNextArea(TextCompositor.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextAreaLayout.layoutChildren(TextAreaLayout.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.TextAreaLayout.layout(TextAreaLayout.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.InlineTextArea.layout(InlineTextArea.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startContent(LayoutEngine.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startText(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startLabel(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startForeign(LayoutEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitContent(LayoutEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.visitChildren(LayoutEngine.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.RegionLayoutEngine.layout(RegionLayoutEngine.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.PageArea.layoutFooter(PageArea.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.PageArea.initialize(PageArea.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.RootArea.createNewPage(RootArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.area.impl.RootArea.initialize(RootArea.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.setContainer(LayoutEngine.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine._startContainer(LayoutEngine.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.nLayout.LayoutEngine.startContainer(LayoutEngine.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterAdapter.startPage(ContentEmitterAdapter.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.CompositeContentEmitter.startPage(CompositeContentEmitter.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.ContentEmitterUtil.startContent(ContentEmitterUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.PageNode.start(PageNode.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.ContainerBufferNode.start(ContainerBufferNode.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.ContainerBufferNode.start(ContainerBufferNode.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.ContainerBufferNode.start(ContainerBufferNode.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.ContainerBufferNode.start(ContainerBufferNode.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.HTMLPageBuffer.startContent(HTMLPageBuffer.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.buffer.TableBreakBuffer.startContent(TableBreakBuffer.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLLeafItemLM.start(HTMLLeafItemLM.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableBandLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableBandLM.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to either:

- Add your font directory to CLASSPATH (or copy/symlink report fonts to any directory in CLASSPATH)
- Register font directory with the following code:

  ```
  import java.security.AccessController;
  import java.security.PrivilegedAction;    
  import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;

  ...

  AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
          public Object run() {
                  FontFactory.registerDirectory(yourFontsDirectory);
                  return null;
          }
  });
  ```

Font directory should contain ttf fonts used by your report design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the locale as `task.setLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));`